# Excel Sumifs for Current Month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to alter my Excel formula so that it manually sums rows from a separate tab for the current month.  (Consider current month here as November.)

The output as is looks like this:

[Picture of Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggc8i.png)

And the formula I'm using for the Current Month column is

=SUMIFS(Expenses!C7:C5003,Expenses!A7:A5003,">=11/1/21",Expenses!A7:A5003,"<=11/30/21",Expenses!E7:E5003,"Groceries")

with the Category changing for each row in the Category column.

As the months change, I have to manually go in and change the dates in each row.  Instead, I would like this to update automatically each month, with the formula as is remaining the same except for where it has the date 11/1/21, I'd like it to indicate the first day of the current month, and for the date 11/30/21, the last day of the current month.

I tried this:

=SUMIFS(Expenses!C7:C5003,Expenses!A7:A5003,">=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1)",Expenses!A7:A5003,"<=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,1)-1",Expenses!E7:E5003,"Groceries")

But no dice.  Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: `">="`,`"<="`---->`">="&`, `"<="&`. And then remove the extra `"` after `...1)`.

Comment: It works.  You are a genius.  THANKS.